# for(auto& x : unordered_map variable) - this statement throwing error

Tags: c++, c++11

Hi my code snippet is as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

struct job
{
    int priority;
    int state;
    std::string name;
};
job* selectJob(std::unordered_map<int, job*> jobList)
{
    for (auto& x : jobList)
    {
        if(x->state == 1)
        return x;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<int, job*> jobList;
    job a = { 1, 1, "a" };
    jobList.insert(std::make_pair<int, job*>(1, &a));
    job *selected = NULL;

    while (NULL != (selected = selectJob(jobList)))
    {
        std::cout << "Name: " << selected->name << "Prio: " << selected->priority << std::endl;
        selected->state = 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled on linux it is throwing an error:

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x q.cpp
q.cpp: In function âjob* selectJob(std::unordered_map<int, job*, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, job*> > >&)â:
q.cpp:13: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before â:â token
q.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before âreturnâ
q.cpp:18: error: expected `;' before âreturnâ
q.cpp:18: error: expected primary-expression before âreturnâ
q.cpp:18: error: expected `)' before âreturnâ
```

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What comes just before this function?

Comment: Do you *really* want to pass an `unordered_map` **by value**?

Comment: Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: Did you compile with the `-std=c++11` flag?

Comment: Yes I compiled with option -std=c++0x

Comment: I tried to compile this on IDEOne - no error

Comment: What compiler version? What's the command line used to compile?

Comment: John: I passed through reference but it is not affecting anything

Comment: Iterating over an `unordered_map` does not yield the value type directly, but a `pair<const Key, Value>`. So `x->state` needs to be `x.second->state` and `return x` needs to be `return x.second`. But that still doesn't explain the error. Please update with which compiler and version you're using.

Comment: With gcc 4.8.0 using `-std=gnu++11` I get a different error. On the `if(x->state == 1)` line the compiler complains that `x` isn't a pointer (since it's a reference to a `pair<const int,job*>`.

Comment: Compiler version is
gcc version 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973] (SUSE Linux)

Comment: x->second returns a job*, not a job, so the selectJob check should be if (x->second && x->second->state == 1).

Comment: Yeah Michael I understood that error but before getting that am stuck with this error

Comment: You need to update your compiler. gcc 4.3.4 was released in August 2009.

Comment: [gcc4.3.4](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html) didn't support type inference using `auto`. (See how quick that was once you posted the relevant information?)

Comment: @user2166368:  Stop and *think* about what I asked you and why I asked it.  I never said it would solve *this* problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler version you're using (gcc 4.3) does not support auto variables.

http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.3/cxx0x_status.html

auto-typed variables    N1984   No

Comment: Arkadiy and Michael Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the `value_type` of an `unordered_map` is a pair of the key and value, you need to select the second.

```
job* selectJob(std::unordered_map<int, job*> jobList)
{
    for (auto& x : jobList)
    {
        if(x->second->state == 1)
        return x->second;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Also you might want to pass by reference to avoid copying and leading to a dangling point.

```
job* selectJob(std::unordered_map<int, job*>& jobList)
```

Comment: This dint solve my error, maybe as Arkadiy mentioned compiler version may not be supporting it

Comment: @user2166368 sure, you need to update your compiler, but your code would still be wrong even once updated.

Comment: Yeah you are correct I will update my compiler and code as well